# phpunit with Zend_Dom_Query

Tags: phpunit, zend-dom-query

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc->loadHTML($docSrc);
$xpath  = new DOMXPath($domDoc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//a[@class='active' and @href='/advanced-2-0.html']");
$this->assertTrue($nodeList->length == 1);
```

This code works great if `$docSrc` is something like this:

```
$docSrc = '<div><a class="active" href = "/advanced-2-0.html']"></div>';
```

but when I assign HTML to `$docSrc` like this:

```
$this->dispatch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$html = $this->getResponse()->getBody();
```

it doesn't work. I print `$html` and everything is ok inside; I can't explain it because in both cases it's a string.

I get the error:

> `AccountControllerTest::testIfAllow
>   DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Namespace prefix fb is not defined in Entity, line: 54`

I also tried:

```
$domDoc->loadHTML("$this->getResponse()->getBody()");
```

Errors don't appear, but the result is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using FBML in your output, e.g. `<fb:like ...>` for a Like button. You can possibly wrap the output in an `<html>` element that declares the namespace.

**Update:** Now that I am looking at our code, we also had to switch to `loadXML()` instead of `loadHTML()` and set libxml's `recover` flag:

```
$html = '<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">'
        . $this->getResponse()->getBody()
        . '</html>';
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc->recover = true; // attempt to handle non-well-formed documents
$domDoc->loadXML($html);
...
```

Comment: Thank you David for responce but your fix doesn't help, the problem is the <fb:like or <fb:login-button; if I remove this code I can parse it but anyway your solution doesn't work for me

Comment: @SergiuGolban Ah, we had to use `loadXML()` instead of `loadHTML()`. See my update.

Comment: Thank you David till the end I found the cause; thirst of all html should be a valid one, becouse I use strict Doctype; in case it isn't a valid one you can't use facebook tag inside; and I just delete it with regex; but the best solution here for me is Selenium, it is more easy